# Get a list of packages installed additionally after Ubuntu installation

Tags: 20.04, package-management

I know I can get a list of all installed packages with `apt list --installed`.

How can I get a list of packages that were additionally installed **after** the installation?

Background: I want to automate the installation of a Ubuntu 20.04.4 via `ansible` and would like to have the subsequently installed packages from a system.

Comment: One start would be to do a clean install to get the baseline, then on a system you want to analyze, `grep "status installed" /var/log/dpkg.log` to get some of the data you need. If the system has existed for a while, you may need to grep more, older dpkg logs. Alternatively you could diff the output of `dpkg -l` on the vanilla install vs the one you want to check.

Comment: @popey: That would be a possibility. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the initial installation packages in /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz, so the below script should show the additional ones you added without the (uninteresting) ones added via update:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```